# How to select the key corresponding to highest value from histogram map?

Tags: amazon-athena

I'm using the `histogram()` function https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html

It "Returns a map containing the count of the number of times each input value occurs."

The result may look something like this:

```
{ORANGES=1, APPLES=165, BANANAS=1}
```

Is there a function that will return `APPLES` given the above input?

**XY Problem?**

The astute reader may notice the end-result of `histogram()` combined with what I'm trying to do, would be equivalent to the mythical *Mode Function*, which exists in textbooks but not in real-world database engines.

Here's my complete query at this point. I'm looking for the most frequently occurring value of `upper(cmplx)` for each `upper(address),zip` tuple:

```
select * from (select upper(address) as address, zip, 
               (SELECT max_by(key, value) 
                FROM unnest(histogram(upper(cmplx))) as t(key, value)),
               count(*) as N
from apartments 
group by upper(address), zip) t1
where N > 3
order by N desc;
```

And the error...

> SYNTAX_ERROR: line 2:55: Constant expression cannot contain column
>   references

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's what I use to get the key that corresponds to the max value from an arbitrary map:

```
MAP_KEYS(mapname)[
                ARRAY_POSITION(
                    MAP_VALUES(mapname),
                    ARRAY_MAX(MAP_VALUES(mapname))
                )
            ]
```

substitute your histogram map for 'mapname'.

Not sure how this solution compares computationally to the other answer, but I do find it easier to read.

Comment: This solution works even when there are multiple rows and multiple columns containing histograms. It seems computationally fine, Athena didn't choke or crash.

Comment: Does Presto guarantee the order of MAP_KEYS and MAP_VALUES to be always consistent? Meaning does the first key in MAP_KEYS corresponds to the first value in MAP_VALUES?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `map` you got from `histogram` to an array with [map_entries](https://docs.starburstdata.com/latest/functions/map.html?highlight=map_entries#map_entries). Then you can [UNNEST](https://docs.starburstdata.com/latest/sql/select.html?highlight=unnest#unnest) that array to a relation and you can call [max_by](https://docs.starburstdata.com/latest/functions/aggregate.html?highlight=max_by#max_by). Please see the below example:

```
SELECT max_by(key, value) FROM (
    SELECT map_entries(histogram(clerk)) as entries from tpch.tiny.orders
)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST (entries) t(key, value);
```

EDIT:

As noted by @Alex R, you can also pass `histogram` results dirrectly to `UNNEST`:

```
SELECT max_by(key, value) FROM ( 
    SELECT histogram(clerk) as histogram from tpch.tiny.orders ) 
CROSS JOIN UNNEST (histogram) t(key, value);
```

In your question the query part `(SELECT max_by(key, value) FROM unnest(histogram(upper(cmplx))` is a correlated subquery which is not yet supported. However the error you are seeing is misleading. IIRC Athena is using Presto 0.172, and this error reporting was fixed in 0.183 (see https://docs.starburstdata.com/latest/release/release-0.183.html - that was in July 2017, btw `map_entries` was also added in 0.183)

Comment: I'm getting `Function map_entries not registered` on Athena :-(

Comment: I believe Athena's `UNNEST` can handle the return from `histogram()` directly. But still I can't get the syntax quite right. See updated question...

Comment: I know it's been 6 months but I'm still unable to get this to work (it's a hobby project). The above query works for a single histogram but not when I have multiple histogram columns. I've tried a bunch of different things and mostly got syntax errors.